# Disable product from using API or filter API

Tags: magento-1.9, product, api, soap-api-v2, soap-api-v1

Is it possible to disable a product to not use the API at all? We have several setup configured, but we also have a lot of product that use the API, but don't need too. I'd be okay to filter by API user. 
That way the product can go to the proper network as I have about dozen or so.

Comment: Will you please specify Magento version.

Comment: Sure I'm using 1.9